# Send event to js from swift or objective-c

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, event-handling

I have created the following class (condensed version), heres a reference to the full file
https://github.com/cotyembry/CastRemoteNative/blob/7e74dbc56f037cc61241f6ece24a94d8c52abb32/root/ios/CastRemoteNative/NativeMethods.swift

```
@objc(NativeMethods)
class NativeMethods: RCTEventEmitter {
  @objc(sendEventToJSFromJS)
  func sendEventToJSFromJS {
    self.emitEvent(eventName: "test", body: "bodyTestString")
  }
  func emitEvent(eventName: String: body: Any) {
    self.sendEvent(withName: eventName, body: body)
  }
}
```

This works perfectly and fires my callback listener that is in my javascript code when I call the `emitEvent` method like the following, its an altered snippet from
https://github.com/cotyembry/CastRemoteNative/blob/7e74dbc56f037cc61241f6ece24a94d8c52abb32/root/js/Components/ChromecastDevicesModal.js

From the javascript side

```
import {
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter
} from 'react-native'

//here I bring in the swift class to use inside javascript
var NativeMethods = NativeModules.NativeMethods;

//create an event emitter to use to listen for the native events when they occur
this.eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeMethods);
//listen for the event once it sends
this.subscription = this.eventEmitter.addListener('test', (body) => { console.log('in test event listener callback', body)});

NativeMethods.sendEventToJSFromJS() //call the native method written in swift
```

I simply have the `sendEventToJSFromJS` method invoked on a button press in javascript

Again, this works and the `console.log('in test event listener callback', body)` code works and runs on the javascript side

My Issue where this does NOT work:

If I was to do the following inside the swift file after defining the class, this would not work:

```
var nativeMethodsInstance = nativeMethods()
nativeMethodsInstance.sendEventToJSFromSwift()
```

Why? Because the following error is thrown:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'bridge is not set. This is probably because you've explicitly synthesized the bridge in NativeMethods, even though it's inherited from RCTEventEmitter.'
```

So, when creating an `instance` of NativeMethods, versus not... what is the difference?

For additional information:

Objective-C gets the same bridge not set issue when I write these same snippets of code in .h and .m files instead of in .swift files

I found where the error message is getting printed in the native code, but it just has the variable

```
_bridge
```

and is checking to see if it is `nil`

The files are this error comes from is:

```
RCTEventEmitter.h
RCTEventEmitter.c
```

here is the full snippet of RCTEventEmitter.c

```
- (void)sendEventWithName:(NSString *)eventName body:(id)body
{


  RCTAssert(_bridge != nil, @"bridge is not set. This is probably because you've "
        "explicitly synthesized the bridge in %@, even though it's inherited "
        "from RCTEventEmitter.", [self class]);

  if (RCT_DEBUG && ![[self supportedEvents] containsObject:eventName]) {
    RCTLogError(@"`%@` is not a supported event type for %@. Supported events are: `%@`",
                eventName, [self class], [[self supportedEvents] componentsJoinedByString:@"`, `"]);
  }
  if (_listenerCount > 0) {
    [_bridge enqueueJSCall:@"RCTDeviceEventEmitter"
                    method:@"emit"
                      args:body ? @[eventName, body] : @[eventName]
                completion:NULL];
  } else {
    RCTLogWarn(@"Sending `%@` with no listeners registered.", eventName);
  }
}
```

Where does this _bridge value get set and how does it get set so I can know, in the cases where it is failing how to set it

I found the following also in RCTEventEmitter.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) RCTBridge *bridge;
```

In the error that is given it mentions the bridge is inherited in the RCTEventEmitter, so is this maybe an issue with the `weak` part to the `bridge` property?

Or do I need to change my strategy in how I'm doing this all together?

I know it probably has to be something to do with me not fully understanding the

```
@synthesize bridge = _bridge;
```

part of the code and all the languages being mixed in doesnt help much lol...

This is really hard, so any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks so much for your time

here is a link to the full project when the project history code represented the code from my question above (since I have since made changes to the project):

https://github.com/cotyembry/CastRemoteNative/tree/7e74dbc56f037cc61241f6ece24a94d8c52abb32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out

**Warning**: this solution uses a deprecated method react native method - I could not figure out how to "properly" inherit from the `RCTEventEmitter` and send an event... every time I tried to the `_bridge` would end up being `nil`

Make sure Swift is bridged to Objective C (if you're using swift to send the event to javascript)

Do **Not** create instances of the exported Native modules (whether they be written in Swift or Objective C)

Let React Native's underlying implementation do this and for each and every class that needs to send an event, export that particular Native Class Objective C Implementation code or Swift code (the Native Module) to React-Native. This allows the javascript to be able to listen to the event

```
var publicBridgeHelperInstance = PublicBridgeHelper()  //instantiate the  the objective c class from inside the .swift file to use later when needing to get a reference to the bridge to send an event to javascript written in react native

@objc(DeviceManager)             //export swift module to objective c
class DeviceManager: NSObject {

  @objc(deviceDidComeOnline:)    //expose the function to objective c
  public func deviceDidComeOnline(_ device: GCKDevice) {
    //imagine this deviceDidComeOnline function gets called from something from the Native code (totally independent of javascript) - honestly this could be called from a native button click as well just to test it works...

    //emit an event to a javascript function that is a in react native Component listening for the event like so:

    //1. get a reference to the bridge to send an event through from Native to Javascript in React Native (here is where my custom code comes in to get this to actually work)
    let rnBridge = publicBridgeHelperInstance.getBridge()  //this gets the bridge that is stored in the AppDelegate.m file that was set from the `rootView.bridge` variable (more on this later)

    //(if you want to print the bridge here to make sure it is not `nil` go ahead:
    print("rnBridge = \(rnBridge)")

    //2. actually send the event through the eventDispatcher
    rnBridge?.eventDispatcher().sendAppEvent(withName: "test", body: "testBody data!!!")
  }
}
```

in `AppDelegate.h` put (additionally to the code that was already in the file)

```
#import "YourProjectsBridgingHeaderToMakeThisCodeAvailableInSwift.h"  //replace this with your actual header you created when creating a swift file (google it if you dont know how to bridge swift to objective c)

@interface PublicBridgeHelper: NSObject
  -(RCTBridge*)getBridge;
@end
```

in `AppDelegate.m` put (in addition to the code that was already in the file)

```
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

RCTBridge *rnBridgeFromRootView;

@implementation PublicBridgeHelper    //this is created to SIMPLY return rnBridgeFromRootView defined above over to my Swift class when actually sending the event to javascript that defines a react native Component
-(RCTBridge*)getBridge {
  NSLog(@"rnBridgeFromRootView = @%@", rnBridgeFromRootView);
  return rnBridgeFromRootView;
}
```

**important** - also make sure to add the following line of code to the Objective C .h's bridging header to make this `PublicBridgeHelper` definition available to be used in the .swift code

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

## finally,

now to show you how to set the rnBridgeFromRootView variable used in AppDelegate.m (that gets returned and used in the .swift code right before sending the event to javascript)

open `AppDelegate.m` and in the method body of

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { ... }
```

include the following after the line of code that instantiates the `rootView` variable

i.e. after the line that probably looks like

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleName:@"YourProjecNameProbably" initialProperties:nil launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

add:

```
rnBridgeFromRootView = rootView.bridge  //set the bridge to  be exposed and returned later and used by the swift class
```

Now to explain the `publicBridgeHelperInstance.getBridge()` part that is in the .swift file

`publicBridgeHelper` is an instance of an objective c class which allows the swift class ability to get a reference to the react native bridge

If you are still having problems understanding my answer after reading this I made a video over it and you can watch it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZj-Vm9cQIg&t=9s

Comment: Why would you mix an objective-c appDelegate with swift code?

Comment: because I needed it to expose the rootView.bridge (i.e. the bridge variable) @thibautnoah to the other parts in the code

Comment: you could probably use the .swift version of the app delegate by adapting the code I used in AppDelegate.m but from what I remember, in Swift it was giving me issues in that language with the methods they were using to allow me to get the bridge (but it has been awhile since I looked at it)

Comment: Didn't have issue to expose it in my app, sublassing RTCEventEmitter on the other hand is the pain.

Comment: @thibautnoah did you use sort of how I did it or did you actually get the subclass to work to send the event

Comment: Neither, you can access the bridge from react-native rootview, i used it to set a reference to my viewController in my extern module (i do this in my viewController, i don't use appDelegate for this)

Comment: When the rootview is created it already has a bridge property set on it and that's what you're using - got ya. Thanks bunches